Can any subgroup be centralizer of some element of $x$?
The stabilizer of an element $x$ of $G$ for the operation of conjugation is called the centralizer of $x$. It is often denoted by $Z(x)$:
$$Z(x)=\{g∈G∣gxg^{-1}=x\}=\{g∈G∣gx=xg\}$$
I know centralizer of $x$ is a subgroup,
conversely, Can any subgroup be centralizer of some element of $x$?
Which I mean, can I find a example of a subgroup that can't be centralizer of any element of $x$?

What happens in an abelian group?

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

Let $G$ be a non-trivial group, and let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of all centralizers of elements of $G$, that is $\mathscr{C}=\{C_G(x): x \in G\}$. This is of course a subset of $\mathscr{H}$, the set of all subgroups of $G$. Then $\mathscr{C} \subsetneq \mathscr{H}$: if not, choose $x \in G$ with $C_G(x)=Z(G)$, the center of $G$. In particular $x \in C_G(x)=Z(G)$, so $x$ is central and thus $C_G(x)=G$. It follows that $G$ is abelian, but then $\mathscr{C}=\{G\}$. Since, $G$ is non-trivial, this cannot be the set of all subgroups of $G$. In other words, in every non-trivial group you can find a subgroup which cannot be realized as the centralizer of some element.

Take the subgroup $S_3$ of the group $S_4$. (In cycle notation)
By which I mean the set $\{ (1) , (1 2) , (1 3) , (2 3) , (1 2 3) , (1 3 2)\}$
inside the group of all permutations of length $4$ ($S_4$)
No element in $S_4$ exists that commutes with just these $6$.
